# Discord.js V13 DEV | message.mentions.users.first() doesn't work!

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm With a Problem With message.mentions.users.first(),

When I'm Execute The Command, My Bot Doesn't Send a Message And Don't Give Me a Error In Terminal! Someone Can Help Me Please?

`luna.on('messageCreate', (message) => { if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'teste') { user = message.mentions.users.first() try { message.channel.send(`oi ${user}``` ) } catch (err) { console.log(``algo deu errado``, err) }   } }) ```

Comment: Por favor, esclareça seu problema ou forneça detalhes adicionais a fim de destacar exatamente o que você precisa. Da forma como está escrito atualmente é difícil dizer com exatidão o que você está perguntando.

Comment: Bem-vindo ao Stack Overflow **em português**. Tal como o nome sugere, o idioma oficial usado aqui é o português. Assim sendo, você poderia por favor traduzir sua pergunta? Caso prefira, você também pode fazer essa mesma pergunta no [site em inglês do Stack Overflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask).

Answer (score 0):

Eu acho que não te aparecia nada no terminal nem mandava mensagem porque devias ter posto o `let` a traz do user(neste caso eu usei `mentionMember`).

```js
luna.on('messageCreate', (message) => {

if (message.content.toLowerCase() === 'teste')

let mentionMember = message.mentions.members.first() 
if (!mentionMember) mentionMember = message.member;

message.channel.send(oi ${mentionMember.user.username}) 

})
```

obs: Da próxima vez tenta mostrar melhor o código :)

Comment: Por favor, adicione mais detalhes para expandir sua resposta, como um código que funcione ou citações de documentação.